# Verificar campo apenas se tiver algum valor Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Pessoal eu tenho um sistema de cadastro de usuário, nesse sistema tem um campo CPF, onde utilizo uma classe para validar o mesmo, porém o campo não é obrigatório, e todas as classes que experimentei para validar o cpf, faz a validação mesmo o campo estando vazio pois entende que o campo vazio não tem um formato de cpf valido. Então minha ideia, para não mexer na classe, é verificar o campo cpf se ele veio vazio/null, para só dai fazer a verificação.

Utilizo dessa forma:

```
    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email|min:3|max:60|unique:users,email,
        'name'     => 'required|min:3|max:70',
        'cpf'      => 'cpf',

    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Tentei usar o required_if mas não consegui formar a logica. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da documentação do [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields).

> By default, Laravel includes the TrimStrings and
>   ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware in your application's global
>   middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the
>   App\Http\Kernel class. **Because of this, you will often need to mark
>   your "optional" request fields as nullable if you do not want the
>   validator to consider null values as invalid.**

```php
$rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|min:3|max:60|unique:users,email',
    'name'     => 'required|min:3|max:70',
    'cpf'      => 'nullable|cpf',

];

$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Em alguns cenários onde o input não é enviado junto com a request, pode-se usar o validador [sometimes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

```php
$rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|min:3|max:60|unique:users,email',
    'name'     => 'required|min:3|max:70',
    'cpf'      => 'sometimes|required|cpf',

];

$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Comment: Fala Vinicius, muito obrigado pela resposta. Inclusive estou usando uma classe criada por você para fazer a validação do cpf, baixei do git. Vou tentar fazer da forma como colocou, logo posto o resultado.

Comment: valeu, muito obrigado mesmo, resolveu meu problema. Parabéns e sucesso.